# Given a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with nonnegative Ricci and level set of a Busemann function

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complete-spaces, ricci-flow

It is known that on a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with nonnegative sectional curvature the Busemann function is convex and hence it's level set is connected.

Suppose we replace nonnegative sectional curvature with nonnegative Ricci curvature, could it be true that the level set of a Busemann function is connected or is a union of finitely many connected component?

Comment: And it's level set is $b_p^{-1}(c)$ for a fixed $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Correction. Busemann function is $b_p(x) = \lim_{r\to\infty}(r - d(x, \partial(B(p,r)))$